# Unable to scrape data from a React.js data grid

Tags: python, selenium, reactjs

I'm trying to scrape a stock price from the NYSE website.  For example, on the [page for IBM](http://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:IBM) I would like to scrape the field corresponding to *Last Price* from within the *Quote* data grid.  I believe that this grid is generated using react.js.  With developer tools in my browser I can locate the desired data:

```html
<span class="rtq-d big" domid="LastPrice">148.95</span>
```

So with the page fully loaded it should be possible to search for a span with `domid="LastPrice"`.  But I cannot seem to get that grid loaded programatically.  It's not particularly surprising that naive scrapers fail at this task, but I've also had trouble using both PhantomJS and Firefox through selenium.  For example the code below suggests that while it's possible to find DOM elements outside the grid, the desired `<span>` *within* the grid cannot be found.  What's strange is that I can actually see the grid loaded in the firefox window (opened by selenium), but even after loading, it does not appear to be reachable programatically.

```py
In [1]: from selenium import webdriver

In [2]: driver = webdriver.Firefox()

In [3]: driver.get('http://www.nyse.com/quote/XNYS:IBM')

In [4]: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="content-1500013182"]')  # outside grid
Out[4]: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a67fa410-8033-472a-8932-ccc40ef026a3", element="{61a9aded-1b9d-4995-9a74-031c3cff5e55}")>

In [5]: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@domid="LastPrice"]')       # inside grid
Out[5]: NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@domid=\"LastPrice\"]"}
```

Am I missing some sort of incantation that will synchronize the selenium driver with what's actually loaded on the page?  Or do I perhaps need run some javascript from the driver to ensure that that page is properly loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span element you want is located in an iframe, which means the span element can't be found directly. To access it you must first direct the webdriver object to switch to the iframe:

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel-body']//iframe")
len(iframes)  # 5
driver.switch_to.frame(iframes[0])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@domid="LastPrice"]')  # should work now
```

Comment: Works as advertised.  Thanks Levi!